# Limit search results to a specific site with DuckDuckGo

Tags: search, duckduckgo

Is it possible to limit the search to specific site using DDG? Much like `site:*.co.uk` on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Yes you can - it is the same syntax.</strike>

> **Site search:**
>
> - You can add `site:domain` to your search to restrict the results to a particular domain, e.g. `duckduckgo site:gabrielweinberg.com`.
> - Click the site icons next to the results (on the left) to do a site search for the domain related to that result. You can also do the same
>     by clicking the 'More results' link to the right of the URL line for a
>     given result.

Extracted [from this DuckDuckGo article](http://help.duckduckgo.com/customer/portal/articles/300304)

You can use the "bangs" functionality and directly search most major sites.

> Or you can type in a command like `!amazon bags`, which will take you
>   to Amazon.com and auto-search it for 'bags'.
>
> We call these commands `!bangs`, and this syntax works for 100s of
>   sites:
>
> - Most big sites work, e.g. `!youtube` (see full list below)
> - Most generic keywords work too, e.g. `!images`
> - There are also shorter versions, e.g. `!g` (google) `!i` (images) `!yt` (youtube)
> - `!ducky` or `'! '` or `'\'` will take you to the first result.
> - `!safeoff` will run a search with safe search off.

See [this DuckDuckGo article](http://duckduckgo.com/bang.html) for more information on how the "bangs" functionality works.

Comment: The "from this DuckDuckGo article" link is not working any more

Comment: I needed this too as I have just switched over and found the docs @KarthikeyanVaithilingam see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can by doing something similar with google, except, as far as I've found, it has to be explicit and you can't use regex patterns or wildcards.

#### To limit *to a specific site*

`<query> site:w3schools.com` or `<query> +site:www.w3schools.com`

#### To *exclude a specific site*

`<query> -site:w3schools.com`

#### To *search with a keyword in url*

`<query> inurl:w3`

[reference](https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/results/syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Source (retrieved november 2020): https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/results/syntax/

The syntax is

```
some search words site:example.com
```

To limit results to a top-level domain, for example Niger's `.ne` , you must not write a leading period:

```
some search words site:ne   # this works

some search words site:.ne  # this does not
```